# Should you not rejoice with your spouse also?

Tags: marriage, sukkot, simchah-joy-happiness, parashat-reeh

> "וְשָׂמַחְתָּ בְּחַגֶּךָ אַתָּה וּבִנְךָ וּבִתֶּךָ וְעַבְדְּךָ וַאֲמָתֶךָ וְהַלֵּוִי וְהַגֵּר וְהַיָּתוֹם וְהָאַלְמָנָה אֲשֶׁר בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ׃ "
>
> You shall rejoice in your festival, with your son, and your daughter, and your manservant, and your maidservant, and the Levite, and the stranger, and the orphan, and the widow, who are inside your gates.

[Deut. 16:13-15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.16.14?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he)

Not with your spouse?  Why not?

Comment: Torah considers your wife to be an extension of you, as in "one flesh."

Comment: Very interestingly, in Deut 14,26 it says **only you and your wife** ("וְשָׂמַחְתָּ אַתָּה וּבֵיתֶךָ"! THe biggest problem is that the Gemmorah (Kiddushin 34?) learns the obligation for women to celebrate but does not bring both Psukim!

Comment: @al Berko it says you and your household.

Comment: The passage mentions the Levite but not the Kohen or Yisroel. Are they excluded too?

Comment: Technically a Cohen is a Levite, and Yisroel are not all poor. But the point you are making is that we do not have to be ultra exacting with the words?

Comment: The Sages said, "En me’arvin simchah b’simchah — do not mix rejoicing and rejoicing.”  So maybe you ARE supposed to postpone rejoicing with your spouse until after you finish rejoicing in the holiday!

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi interesting problem you have raised.. I think the resolution is that 1) The idea is to "rejoice with everyone; especially these people.." during the holiday. There are no 2 events competing here. There is one idea: "rejoice on the holiday". Otherwise, how could you rejoice with your son when the verse says daughter as well?? do not mix rej w rej?! 2) Your obligation to rejoice with your wife is 24/7 AFAIK,... so not mixing rej vs rej applies when you can reschedule one of them. It cannot apply to rej w one's wife since even missing one day can never be made up. :)

Comment: If the wife were listed it would only detract from her importance. She is part of her husband and is therefore the subject, not one of the secondary objects.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Your answer is tempting to say, but there are lots of Psukim mentioning the wife explicitly, making this Pasuk an exception. So the question stands WHY?.

Comment: @AlBerko Can you provide the verses you mean? It would help to compare them.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Rashi explains basar echad differently, so this is still a question according to him.

Answer (score 4):

Your observation - of the missing wife in the verse - is the basis for the halacha that one may not get married during Chag.

See the [Torah Temima](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.16.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.16.14.5&lang2=bi) and the [Rabeinu Bachyeh](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.16.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Devarim.16.14.1-2&lang2=bi) on the verse that mention this.

Regarding the actual question, see the [Ibn Ezra in verse 14:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.14.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.14.26.3&lang2=bi) who mentions that you and your sons have an obligation to go to the Mikdash on the 3 festivals, whereas your wife and daughters do not.

> אתה וביתך. אתה ובניך חיוב וביתך רשות כי מצות שלש פעמים על הזכרים והאשה ההולכת למקום הנבחר כנשי אלקנה יש להן שכר:‏
>
> You and your household you and your sons are obliged, whereas the rest of your household are permitted. The commandment to observe the three festivals is binding only upon males [Exodus 23: 17]; but those women will be rewarded who, like the wives of  Elqanah, [I Samuel 1: 3 ff .], go on pilgrimage to the appointed place.

So possibly the verse you mentioned excluded the wife, not because you don't have an obligation to rejoice with her, but because she may not be around, since she may have opted to remain at home - yet this wouldn't give you an excuse to remain with her.